# Is there a pythonic way to get the beginning and end indexes of clusters of identical values in an iterable?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing, iterable

The following question can easily be solved with a loop, but I suspect that there may be a more pythonic way of acheiving this.

In essence, I have an iterable of booleans that tend to be clustered into groups.  Here's an illustrative example:

`[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True]`

I'd like to pick out the beginning index and end index for each cluster of `True`s.  Using a loop, this is easy -- each time my iterator is a `True`, I simply need to check if I'm already in a `True` cluster.  If not, I set the `in_true_cluster` variable to true and store the index.  Once I find a `False`, I store index - 1 as the end point.

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?  Note that I'm using PANDAS and NumPy as well, so solutions using logical indexing are acceptable.

Comment: Why do you think that using a loop is not pythonic?

Comment: It's easy enough to get this from [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), possibly combined with `enumerate`. I bet there's a better way with pandas/numpy, though.

Comment: @poke, Sure it's pythonic.  I'm wondering if there's a clearer/simpler way of doing things?  Also, loops tend to be slow and this is a massive structure (a PANDAS series of about 3 million elements) -- canned approaches tend to be optimized.

Comment: @Dougal, Hmm good call.  PANDAS actually has a really groupby functionality -- That seems to be the obvious approach, now that I think about it!

Comment: @blz Unless there is magic involved, most solutions use loops internally anyway. And I don’t think some crazy one-line things are simpler than a simple for loop with a clear intent. And you do need to look at every object anyway, so you can just as well loop yourself.

Comment: @poke, often times these loops are implemented directly in C, thus reducing iteration time -- take `map` for example.  Vectorized methods are even faster.

Comment: @poke In the numpy/pandas world, python loops are *crazy* slower than using numpy functions because of the very high overheads in python. I added timings to my answer.

Comment: @Jaime, I humbly submit that this question is not an exact duplicate due to the invovlement of PANDAS.  This is especially relevant since NumPy and PANDAS are often used in conjunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, here's a numpy way, which should be faster than doing it with `itertools` or a manual loop:

```
>>> a = np.array([True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True])
>>> np.diff(a)
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> _.nonzero()
(array([3, 6]),)
```

As you mention in the comments, pandas's [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) would also work.

---

Timings to convince @poke this is worthwhile:

```
>>> %%timeit a = np.random.randint(2, size=1000000)
... np.diff(a).nonzero()
...
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
>>> def cluster_changes(array):
...     changes = []
...     last = None
...     for i, elt in enumerate(array):
...         if elt != last:
...             last = elt
...             changes.append(i)
...     return changes
...
>>> %%timeit a = np.random.randint(2, size=1000000)
cluster_changes(a)
...
1 loops, best of 3: 348 ms per loop
```

That's a factor of 30 on this array using the one-liner, as compared to the 7-line manual function. (Of course, the data here has many more cluster changes than OP's data, but that's not going to make up for such a big difference.)

Comment: Brilliant!  The thought of using the derivative had crossed my mind, but I seem to have misplaced my mojo today.  Thanks for the snippet!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
In [25]: l = [True, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True]

In [26]: d = np.diff(np.array([False] + l + [False], dtype=np.int))

In [28]: zip(np.where(d == 1)[0], np.where(d == -1)[0] - 1)
Out[28]: [(0, 3), (7, 11)]
```

Here, the two runs are at indices `[0; 3]` and `[7; 11]`.